# mongodb retrieve documents and aggregation at same time

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all documents match the filters and also get the total count and sum of the "quantity" field of the returned documents. I can use find + aggregation to achieve what I want, but I'm wondering is there a better way to do this?

Comment: People typically achieve this using `$facet`. I'm sure there are some examples/duplicate questions here the you can take a look at

Answer (score 1):

The `$facet` stage allows you to perform multiple independent aggregations on the same set of input documents, providing separate result sets for each aggregation. In your case, you can combine the filtering and aggregation steps into a single query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { /* Your filters */ }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      totalCount: [{ $count: "total" }],
      sumQuantity: [{ $group: { _id: null, totalQuantity: { $sum: "$quantity" } } }],
      documents: [$match: { /* Your filters */ }]
    }
  }
])
```

You can add `documents` sub pipeline to the `$facet` stage.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I also want the resulting documents returned

Comment: Please check, hopefully it should work unable to test now